# ggbiplot function in R

Tags: r

How can I install ggbiplot function in R? When I try to install, it gives me the following error:

> install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
> Error in install_github("vqv/ggbiplot") :
> could not find function "install_github"

Comment: The error message is telling you that the function `install_github()` was not found. Have you installed the package containing the function with `install.packages()` and loaded it with `library()`?

Comment: You should install and load `remotes` or `devtools` package

Comment: You should also show us what code you have used up to this point for clarification.